# awk - nested search through file?

Tags: awk

I have a file that lists macros and the script elements used within them. I've been able to, if I know the name of the script, search the file line by line and print any macros that use it. That's great! Much thanks to those here who helped. Issue I have now is I'd like to loop through the file, finding each script and printing the macros that use it. I'd think that might be a nested for loop, first finding each script, then testing each macro but haven't come close to figuring it out.

- each line lists either a script or macro.
- each line has $1 as either "SCR" or "MAC" to categorize it.
- each line has $4 as a long string, a unique id (example = RS1c80952b46129fc3bbf7b6d35e52f581d5d96edf).
- each line has $6 as the name of the script or macro.
- each macro line has $7 to NF listing the script id's that it uses, with an underscore prepended (example = _RS1c80952b46129fc3bbf7b6d35e52f581d5d96edf).

This is an actual example line for a script:

```
    SCR 4 0 RS1c80952b46129fc3bbf7b6d35e52f581d5d96edf "Custom: AUDIOBOOKS____ITEM_Select_on_selected_track_by_item_name____fill_1000ms.lua" /home/babag/Downloads/Reaper/ReaScripts/Scripts/BABAG/lua/AUDIOBOOKS____ITEM_Select_on_selected_track_by_item_name____fill_1000ms.lua
```

and these are two actual macro lines that use the above script:

```
    MAC 1 0 "fad0ff7281777ae665363b96d96f1651" "Custom: AUDIOBOOKS____REPLACE_WITH_1000ms_ROOMTONE" _BR_SAVE_CURSOR_POS_SLOT_1 _SWS_SAVETIME1 _RSdebf6a0296631b3e9ce8c88c82d5d3da56e345de _RS1c80952b46129fc3bbf7b6d35e52f581d5d96edf 40698 _SWS_UNSELONTRACKS _SWS_RESTTIME1 _RSc48877ad5413b689c4abf510e70edfb7b138002c 40310 40718 _SWS_XFDOFF 40061 40630 40006 _SWS_AWPASTE _BR_RESTORE_CURSOR_POS_SLOT_1 40630 40635 40289 _SWS_HSCROLL50  
    MAC 1 0 "9d4aa8bac6f7cb3d76c673dd2639152b" "Custom: AUDIOBOOKS____PASTE_AT_CURSOR_wRIPPLE_1000ms_ROOMTONE" _BR_SAVE_CURSOR_POS_SLOT_1 _SWS_SAVETIME1 _RSdebf6a0296631b3e9ce8c88c82d5d3da56e345de _RS1c80952b46129fc3bbf7b6d35e52f581d5d96edf 40698 _SWS_UNSELONTRACKS _SWS_RESTTIME1 _RSc48877ad5413b689c4abf510e70edfb7b138002c 40310 40718 _SWS_XFDOFF _SWS_AWPASTE _BR_RESTORE_CURSOR_POS_SLOT_1 40289
```

I use this to find script lines:

```
awk -v s='RS1c80952b46129fc3bbf7b6d35e52f581d5d96edf' '$1=="SCR"{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) if($i==s) {print $6; next}}' inputfile.txt
```

I use this to find macro lines:

```
awk -v s='_RS1c80952b46129fc3bbf7b6d35e52f581d5d96edf' '$1=="MAC"{for(i=7;i<=NF;i++) if($i==s) {print $6; next}}' inputfile.txt
```

I can't figure out at all how to marry these and make them talk to each other to list each script and the macros it appears in. The output would like something like:

```
scriptname1 is used in the following macros:  
macroname  
macroname  
macroname

scriptname2 is used in the following macros:  
macroname  
macroname  
macroname  

scriptname3 is used in the following macros:  
macroname  
macroname  
macroname
```

Comment: You've not provided any sample data.   That means we can't help you.  Please read about how to create an  MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  Note that an MCVE includes sample input data as well as the expected and actual outputs.  Also note the 'minimal' part of MCVE.  Eliminate the irrelevant.

Comment: thanks, jonathan. the lines in the file are often long so i thought it might be better to try to be concise in describing. since you've asked, i've added an example of the actual script line data as well as four macro lines that use it. it does seem to make things long, though. thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for the changes. I had quite a bit of trouble translating between the actual docs and something that would display properly on the web

Comment: Please see [mcve] for what kind of example to post (you have small blocks of text and large blocks of text and I can't tell input from output and don't know why there's so much text in the large blocks, etc.), and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format it (some of your smaller blocks are formatted correctly but your larger ones aren't). See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. I took out a couple of the example lines which shortens things a lot. If it's not obvious, this is far from my area of expertise. My worry is that, in posting the lines from the text file I need to parse, things like spaces and other important things might get altered, making the lines useless. That's why I, at first, chose to try to describe clearly what the question and issues are. Obviously, this is not working and has become a useless endeavor. Thanks again. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you want to parse the file twice: once to collect the scripts, then again to examine the macros.

```sh
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        if ($1 == "SCR") script["_"$4] = $6
        next
    }
    $1 == "MAC" {
        for (i=7; i<=NF; i++)
            if ($i in script)
                script_uses[$i] = script_uses[$i] $6 ORS
    }
    END {
        for (id in script_uses)
            printf "%s is used in macros:\n%s\n", script[id], script_uses[id]
    }
' file file
```

If the file contains:

```
MAC 1 0 12345 x MACRO1  _foo _bar _567 _baz _987 _qux
SCR 4 0 567   x SCRIPT1 /path/to/script1
MAC 1 0 2354  x MACRO2  _abc _987 _def _ghi
SCR 4 0 987   x SCRIPT2 /path/to/script2
```

Then the output is

```
SCRIPT2 is used in macros:
MACRO1
MACRO2

SCRIPT1 is used in macros:
MACRO1
```